# RegEx to validate URL patterns

Tags: javascript, regex

RegEx to validate URL patterns

I need help with a regular expression to validate any of the following URL patterns. The * is a wildcard.

```
https://google.com
https://www.google.com
https://www.google.com/*
https://*.google.com/
https://*.google.com/asdasdas/*
```

So far I have this:

```bash
https:\/\/(w{3}|\*)?(?:\.[\w\.-]+){2,}[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\?:(*)\+,;=.]+$
```

But is failing on the first case, a domain pattern without "www" or "*" before the first dot.

Keep in mind that instead of google.com it could be any domain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/a/190405/795683

Comment: @SainPradeep no, that response doesnt cover the wildcard cases that I have. Thanks anyway

Comment: try this https:\/\/(w{3}|\*)?(?:\.?[\w\.-]+){2,}[\w\-\._~:\/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\?:(*)\+,;=.]+$

Comment: It's not clear what you're aiming to do exactly, but I might add that `JavaScript` has a [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) object that you could use to validate/parse `URL`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex could be the one that you're looking for:

```
^https:\/\/(((www)|\*)\.)?([\w*]+\.)([\w]+\/?)+\*?$
```

Comment: Thanks but is validating the www part properly. For example, with your solution https://ww.google.com or https://wqwe.google.com are true.

Comment: Thanks Cristiano, seems to be working properly!

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match with the urls you provided and also urls with subdomains:

```
/^https:\/\/([www]|[*]\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_+.~#?&\/\/=].*)?/gmi
```

You can check the result or the explanation here:
https://regex101.com/r/cITjMZ/1

Comment: Thanks but is not validating the www part properly. For example, with your solution ww.google.com or wqwe.google.com are true

Comment: Actually they can be valid addresses, for example "[https://url.spec.whatwg.org/](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/)" is a valid URL and does not have the classic "www".
As a solution it is a bit more universal, but if it is not what you are looking for, the answer of @cristiano-schiaffella is right for your case